# Insert multiple records don't work

Tags: visualforce, query, limits

I have a visualforce page where I insert 7 records at once. 
Each record has 14 fields.

When I only seize some of the fields, the query works, the 7 records are created. But when I seize more, the query doesn't work. There is no redirection. no exeption.

edit: here is the code

```
public PageReference saveImmo() {


    Date debutDate = Date.parse('1/1/'+Year);

    Map<String,Map<String,Decimal>> listMap = new Map<String,Map<String,Decimal>>();

    listMap.put('MONTANT BRUT DEBUT EXERCICE',m1);
    listMap.put('AUGMENTATION Acquisition',m2);
    listMap.put('AUGMENTATION Production',m3);
    listMap.put('AUGMENTATION Virement',m4);
    listMap.put('DIMINUTION Cession',m5);
    listMap.put('DIMINUTION Retrait',m6);
    listMap.put('DIMINUTION Virement',m7); 

    for (String key : listMap.keySet()) {

        T4_IMMO__c immo1 = new T4_IMMO__c();
        immo1.IF__c = IdFisc;
        immo1.Exercice_debut__c = debutDate;
        immo1.Colonne__c = key;

        Map<String,Decimal> m1 = listMap.get(key);

        immo1.Frais_pr_liminaires__c=m1.get('Frais_pr_liminaires__c');
        immo1.Charges_repartir_plusieurs_exercices__c = m1.get('Charges_repartir_plusieurs_exercices__c');  
        immo1.Primes_de_remboursement_des_obligations__c = m1.get('Primes_de_remboursement_des_obligations__c');
        immo1.Immobilisation_recherche_d_veloppement__c = m1.get('Immobilisation_recherche_d_veloppement__c');
        immo1.Brevets_marques_droits_et_similaires__c = m1.get('Brevets_marques_droits_et_similaires__c');
        immo1.Fonds_commercial__c = m1.get('Fonds_commercial__c');
        immo1.Autres_immobilisations_incorporelles__c = m1.get('Autres_immobilisations_incorporelles__c');
        immo1.Terrains__c = m1.get('Terrains__c');
        immo1.Constructions__c = m1.get('Constructions__c');
        immo1.Installat_tech_mat_riel_et_outillage__c = m1.get('Installat_tech_mat_riel_et_outillage__c');
        immo1.Mat_riel_de_transport__c = m1.get('Mat_riel_de_transport__c');
        immo1.Mobilier_mat_riel_bureau_et_am_nagement__c = m1.get('Mobilier_mat_riel_bureau_et_am_nagement__c');
        immo1.Autres_immobilisations_corporelles__c = m1.get('Mobilier_mat_riel_bureau_et_am_nagement__c');
        immo1.Immobilisations_corporelles_en_cours__c = m1.get('Immobilisations_corporelles_en_cours__c');  

        insert immo1;

    }

    return Page.Allimmossaved;
    }
}
```

page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listLabels}" var="dirKey" width="100%" columnsWidth="20%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%">
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">
<center> Nature </center> </apex:facet>
{!$ObjectType.T4_IMMO__c.fields[dirKey].label}
</apex:column>

<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">
       <center> Montant Brut <br/>
        Début de l'exercice </center>
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m1[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">
       <center> Augmentation <br/>
        Acquisition </center>
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m2[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header" >
        <center>Augmentation <br/>
        Production <br/>
        de l'entreprise<br/>
         pour elle-même</center> 
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m3[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header" >
        <center>Augmentation <br/>
        Virement 
        </center>
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m4[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>


<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header" >
        <center>Diminution <br/>
        Cession 
        </center>
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m5[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header" >
        <center>Diminution <br/>
        Retrait 
        </center>
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m6[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header" >
        <center>Diminution <br/>
        Virement
        </center>
     </apex:facet> 
<apex:inputText value="{!m7[dirKey]}" styleClass="myClass"/>
</apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >

<apex:commandButton value="Sauvegarder" action="{!saveImmo}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

EDIT: Fixed the problem! Turns out I was putting numbers with 10005,24 instead of 10005.24. and this is why I couldn't insert the records

Comment: Pls share some code else this is very unclear

Comment: I've added the code, hope it's more clear now

Comment: Can you post your debug log?

Answer (score 3):

I have a few suggestions on how you can improve the code and debug this.

1) As Victor stated, create a list of T4_IMMO__c `(List<T4_IMMO__c> recordsToInsert)` to insert and move the insert statement out from the for loop.

2) Wherever possible use SObject get, put methods to set your field values.

eg:-

```
for(String fieldName : m1.keySet()){
    immo1.put(fieldName, m1.get(fieldName));
}
```

3)Use Database.insert to insert the records:

```
Database.SaveResult[] insertResults = Database.insert(recordsToInsert, false);
```

Then check the insert operations' results by

```
for(Database.SaveResult result : insertResults) {
     if(!result.isSuccess()) {
         System.debug(result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
     }
}
```

If you can't figure out what's wrong by the error messages printed, post the debug log.

Comment: it displays this error
`23:37:34.143 (143296418)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0`

Comment: I forget to add a check for proper inserts in the code. Check the new code

Comment: it displays no error, still the same old debug log. with less numbers it works.

Comment: Fixed the problem! Turns out I was putting numbers with 10005,24 instead of 10005.24

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement is inside for loop. That is not a best practice. It will call insert statements as many times as the length of map. Declare a list of T4_IMMO__c add the instances to the list and finally call insert only once outside the loop.

But this will not address your problem. Could you please post debug log also.

Comment: Added the debug log